# limit in p-adic number system

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Please give me a hint for limit of $lim_{n\to\infty}3^{2^n}$ in $\mathbb Q_5$.

First, new absolute value $|\cdot|'$ on $\mathbb Q$ is defined as the following:

For $\frac{n}{m}\in \mathbb Q$,$$|\frac{n}{m}|'=5^{-v}$$ 
if $\frac{n}{m}=5^vp_1^{v_1}p_2^{v_2}p_3^{v_3}...p_r^{v_r}$ where $p_i$: distinct prime number without 5 and $v_i\in\mathbb Z$.

Then, the absolute value satisfies $|r|'=0 
 \Leftrightarrow r=0$ and triangle inequiality. Secondly, based on this absolute value and equivalence relation for Cauchy sequence, new $\mathbb Q_5$
system is constructed.

Comment: $3^{2^2} \equiv 3^{2^5} \equiv 6 \bmod 25$

Comment: Do you see why it answers your question ? What is $|3^{2^2}-3^{2^3}|$ and $|3^{2^{3n+2}}-(3^{2^{3n+3}})|$ ?

Comment: No $|6-36|= ? $. For the $2^{2n+2}$ see my first comment indicating the sequence $x_n = 3^{2^n}=x_{n-1}^2\bmod 25$ is $3$-periodic

Comment: Isn't it $|6-36|'=-1/5$?

Comment: No $|-30|= |-6| |5|= |5| = 1/5$. It is a norm, no negative values

Comment: Thank you, it was a mistake

Comment: How can i know that it's three periodic?

Comment: Because $x_n = x_{n-1}^2$ is a recurrence with one-backward lookup. So $x_0 = x_3$ implies...

Comment: I thought about it for a quite long time but I can't get answer..could you please give me some solution in detail?

Comment: Umm, could you check your very first computation, @reuns? I get $3^{2^2}\equiv6\pmod{25}$ and $3^{2^5}\equiv16\pmod{25}$ . It really is implausible in the extreme that there would be any kind of $3$-periodicity in a simple five-adic situation like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a moderately delicate question. Let’s look at $3^{2^{n+2}}$ modulo $25$. We have:
$$
3^{2^{n+2}}=3^{4\cdot2^n}=81^{2^n}=(1+5\cdot16)^{2^n}\equiv(1+5)^{2^n}\equiv1+2^n\cdot5\pmod{25}
$$
Now, you can check that for $n\equiv0,1,2,3\pmod4$, you get $2^n\equiv1,2,4,3\pmod5$ respectively, in other words, $3^{2^{n+2}}\equiv6,11,21,16\pmod{25}$ respectively, so there’s nothing like a limit here.

In fact the situation is even worse (or better, depending on your taste). Using the $5$-adic logarithm, you can show that when you restrict to values of $n\equiv0\pmod4$, the numbers $(1+5\cdot16)^{2^n}$ are dense in $6+25\Bbb Z_5$, and similarly for $n\equiv1\pmod4$, the numbers $(1+5\cdot16)^{2^n}$ are dense in $11+25\Bbb Z_5$, etc. But this density question involves more work than you want to see now.

The moral is: no limit.

Answer (score 1):

By repeated squaring we have $3^4\equiv 6\bmod 25$, $3^8\equiv 11$, $3^{16}\equiv 21$, $3^{32}\equiv 16$, $3^{64}\equiv 6$ so the expression cycles $\bmod 25$.  The terms in the cycle differ by amounts having $5$-adic norm $1/5$ which never goes to zero.  So there cannot be a $5$-adic limit.

Comment: As an old hand at this $p$-adic racket, I would say that it looks highly improbable that there could be any satisfactory limit here.

Comment: Similarly the decimal number $0.9999999...$ does not equal $1$ in the $3$-adic metric because the series it represents does not converge.

Comment: Your argument is quicker than mine, but the cycling is even more fractal, if you will: there’s cycling modulo $125$ as well. And modulo $625$, $3125$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're repeatedly squaring in the limit, if the limit exists,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} 3^{2^n} = L$$

then it must end up satisfying $L^2=L$. So either L=0 or L=1. It's not 0 because 3 is not divisible by 5, so it must be 1 if it exists. That means this limit must be zero:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 3^{2^n} - 1 = 0$$

We can factor that pretty easily by a geometric series, for reference:

$$\frac{3^{2^n}-1}{3-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} 3^k$$

so we can rewrite the previous limit as,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2*\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} 3^k = 0$$

in the limit if this sum converges (it doesn't), it should converge to:

$$2 * \frac{1}{1-3}$$

which is not 0, so the limit does not exist.